# Implementing Generic Abstract Factory

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to use a Generic Abstract Factory in C#

I'm following this example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21043/Generic-Abstract-Factory

I have 2 questions.

First: Dependency Injection (I use Unity)

```
public class ClientFactory
{
    private readonly IFactory<Car> _carFactory;

    public ClientFactory(IFactory<Car> carFactory)
    {
        _carFactory = carFactory;
    }
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
var client = new ClientFactory(new Car()); //(this is what the IoC does)
```

Now to be able to inject a `fakeCar` I Did this:

```
public class CarFake : IFactory<Car>
{
    public TProduct Build<TProduct>() where TProduct : IProduct<Car>, new()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating FakeCar: " + typeof(TProduct));
        return new TProduct();
    }
}
```

So, to call it:

```
var client = new ClientFactory(new CarFake()); Is this ok?
```

The second question is:

How do I pass parameters to the concrete products (constructor parameters), lets say `Honda(long id, string model)`, I would like to say:

```
IProduct<Car> carProducta = _carFactory.Build< Honda(Id:1,Model:"Civic") >();
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't understand why you pass in `new Car()` to the car factory, unless the `Car` type *is* the factory?

Comment: The code in that article adds way too much unnecessary complication for something fairly simple. It's practically pointless to use that pattern at all if you're using your DI framework properly

Comment: "Generic Abstract Factory" - sounds like `ninject` IOC container. Why reinvent?